# discord.py on_server_join error

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I want to make some code that makes it so when the bot joins the server, it notifies everybody.

Here's my code currently:

```
@bot.event
async def on_server_join(ctx, server):
    botinvitelink = 'https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=413782934009675776&permissions=8&scope=bot'
    for server_member in ctx.message.server.members:
        await bot.send_message(server_member, "Thanks for using MBot!, click [here] to invite me!({})".format(botinvitelink))
```

the error is this tho:

```
        yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_server_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'server'
```

Comment: You don't need `ctx` as this is an event

Comment: realised that, thanks!